# How can multisig trigger an action in contract other than eosio.token contract?

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, eosio-code, permissions, inline-action

Other than `eosio.token` contract how can we call the inline actions in contract from multisig contract. 
For example,

I have a contracts namely `mltisigmetup`(with action `meetup`). 
Now I need a functionality that `EOSIO.MSIG` will execute `mltisigmetup`'s action `meetup`.

```
cleos multisig propose testfin '[{"actor": "partner2", "permission": 
"active"}]' '[{"actor": "partner2", "permission": "active"}]' mltisigmetup 
meetup '{ "timestamp" :12345567, "author" : "partner1", "male":"ash" , 
"female":"swa","ismet":"yes" }' -p partner1@active -p partner1
```

this following not executing action in ctr

```
 cleos multisig exec partner1 testfin -p partner1
```

multisigmetup.cpp

```
  #include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using namespace eosio;
using namespace std;

class mltisigmetup : public contract
{
    using contract::contract;

  public:
    explicit mltisigmetup(account_name self) : contract(self){}

[[eosio::action]]
void meetup(const uint64_t timestamp, const account_name author,const string &male,const string &female,const string &ismet)
{
        // require_auth(author);
       uint128_t skey = static_cast<uint128_t>(author) << 64 | timestamp;
        meet_table meettable(_self, _self); // code, scope
        meettable.emplace(author, [&](auto &post) {
            post.pkey = meettable.available_primary_key();
            post.skey = skey;
            post.author = author;
        });
    }
 private : struct [[eosio::table]] meet_struct {
        uint64_t pkey;
        uint64_t author;
        uint128_t skey;

        uint64_t primary_key() const { return pkey; }
        uint128_t get_by_skey() const { return skey; }
        EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(meet_struct, (pkey)(author)(skey))
    };
    typedef eosio::multi_index<N(posts), meet_struct,
                               indexed_by<N(getbyskey), const_mem_fun<meet_struct, uint128_t, &meet_struct::get_by_skey>>>
        meet_table;
}; 
EOSIO_ABI(mltisigmetup, (meetup))
```

getting no error, but no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `partner2` transaction auth in contract action data inorder to execute , not partner1's

> { "timestamp" :12345567, "author" : "partner2",....}

```
cleos multisig propose testfin '[{"actor": "partner2", "permission": "active"}]' '[{"actor": "partner2", "permission": "active"}]' mltisigmetup meetup '{ "timestamp" :12345567, "author" : "partner2", "male":"ash" , "female":"swap","ismet":"yes" }' -p partner1
```

aprove

```
cleos multisig approve partner1 testfin '{"actor": "partner2", "permission": "active"}' -p partner2
```

exec

```
cleos multisig exec partner1 testfin -p partner1
```

check table

```
cleos get table mltisigmetup mltisigmetup posts
```